# Binding functions to buttons in Tkinter to create a folder structure

Tags: python, tkinter, button, binding

Trying to create a GUI with 1 button which once pressed will create a folder structure.
I've got the two programmes to work independently but not sure how to bind it in Tkinter to run and create the folder structure once the button is pressed?

```
`from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def printName(event):
    print("config folder created")

button_1 = Button(root, text="config folder")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()`

    import os

#Create a folder structure
project = "01"
app = "app"
mw = "me"
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"
d = "d"
e = "e"
f = "f"

root = "C:\\Users\\user_name\\Documents"
path = f"{root}/{project}/{app}/{mw}/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}".lower().replace(" ","")
print(path)

#If path exists don't create
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code after `root.mainloop()` will not be executed until the root window is closed or destroyed.

Simply move the code after `root.mainloop()` into `printName()` function:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

def printName(event):
    #Create a folder structure
    project = "01"
    app = "app"
    mw = "me"
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"
    d = "d"
    e = "e"
    f = "f"

    root = "C:\\Users\\user_name\\Documents"
    path = f"{root}/{project}/{app}/{mw}/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}".lower().replace(" ","")
    print(path)

    #If path exists don't create
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
        print("config folder created")

button_1 = Button(root, text="config folder")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function that creates your path and then you have to bind that function to the button.
And make sure you don't have any arguments after the

```
root.mainloop()
```

because this is like an infinte while loop and nothing will be executed after it.
Also make sure to define your function before you bind it to the button, because otherwise you can't bind it to the button as it isn't defined yet.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()

def printName(event):
    print("config folder created")

def create_folders(event):
    #Create a folder structure
    project = "01"
    app = "app"
    mw = "me"
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"
    d = "d"
    e = "e"
    f = "f"

    root = "C:\\Users\\user_name\\Documents"
    path = f"{root}/{project}/{app}/{mw}/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}".lower().replace(" ","")
    print(path)

    #If path exists don't create
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="config folder")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
button_1.pack()
button_1.bind(create_folders)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Many thanks but the last bit 
'button_1.bind(create_folders)' doesn't seem to work, if I add in 
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", create_folders) instead of the button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName) then it does, but it doesn't say "config folder created".